# Achieving modal view feature in Android

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-view

My goal is to set a modal view in my Android application. I would like to open one view whose background would be transparent so the user can see the view behind.

1. I've heard about using transparent activity but this might freeze the activity behind, ain't it ?
2. I would like some kind of reusable stuff since this view will call in more than one activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an Activities background transparent using this style:

```
<style name="TransparentActivity" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Declared in the manifest like so:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activity.DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentActivity" >
```

I then use this as the layout for my dialogue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerPageContainer">

    <FrameLayout    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/panel_picture_frame_bg_focus_blue"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/dialog"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

You can either inflate other layouts and add it to `@+id/dialog` or use fragments (depending on how brave you are).

Hope that helped!

Comment: If I've an animation over the first activity, will we still seeing it ?

Comment: Yes you will still see it although because there is a layer on top of your old activity, it will call onPause() on it. I'm not sure if that will pause the animation or not. The only way to layer something onto of your activity and NOT have it call onPause() is to create the "layer" dynamically as part of the same activity AFAIK.

Comment: I have a seek bar in the first view which is still moving while the second view is running inside a transparent activity ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)? You can use a custom content view to display whatever you want, and use `setCancelable(false)`.

Comment: Custom content view inside a Dialog doesn't fit my needs, it's still a dialog.